# Jmeter JSON EXtractor

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter after an HTTP request is made, I have a JSON response data like below and I like to get the list of all `accountId`.

```
{"firstPage":"http://192.168.30.98/XX/v3.0/accounts?pageno=1","lastPage":"http://192.168.30.98/XX/v3.0/accounts?pageno=36","nextPage":"http://192.168.30.98/XX/v3.0/accounts?pageno=2","previousPage":null,"results":[{"accountId":220,"name":"abc2","url":"http://192.168.30.98/XX/v3.0/accounts/220"},{"accountId":1,"name":"ZZ1","url":"http://192.168.30.98/XX/v3.0/accounts/1"},{"accountId":7,"name":"ZZ2018-03-28T22:18:55.393Z","url":"http://192.168.30.98/XX/v3.0/accounts/7"},{"accountId":8,"name":"ZZ2018-03-28T22:23:11.081Z","url":"http://192.168.30.98/XX/v3.0/accounts/8"},{"accountId":9,"name":"ZZ2018-03-28T22:27:54.129Z","url":"http://192.168.30.98/XX/v3.0/accounts/9"},{"accountId":10,"name":"ZZ2018-03-....................}
```

I see that `JSON Extractor` can help me so I added it after my HTTP req. tree:

```
Names of created variables: = accoutnId

JSON Path expression = $..accountId

Match No: -1

compute .. = checked
```

When I run the test in `View Result Tree` I still see the list like above, and I do not see any, `accountId_1` or `accountId_2`.

So I thought maybe because I don't have the JSON Plugins, I went to, `Options --> Plugin Manager --> Available Plugins` then I found `JSON plugins (deprecated)` I installed it anyway

Restarted Jmeter

Re-ran the test

but I still do not see the JSON extracted accountIds?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
Names of created variables: = accoutnId
```

There might be some spelling mistake becasue You are asking for "accountId_1 .. or accountId_2 ". There is spelling mistake in "accoutnId" and "accountId_1 ".

Refer Below Images

[image: Json Extractor]

[image: Json Parmater for exracting single value]

Comment: I have tried everything, I tried , JSON Path Expression: $..accountId   it is not giving me results I have added JSR223 Assertion to OUT.println(Z1);    where  Z1 is name of created variable in JSON extractor . I get null

Comment: From Options --> plug in manager --> Installed Plugins I see JSON plugins (deprecated) I think deprecated means disapproved  did I download a wrong JSON extractor plugin ?

Comment: @user3556956 can you share the link .

Comment: @user3556956 you can use json extractor from  Thread Group > Post Processor > Json Extractor which works fine in Apache Jmter 4.0

Comment: so first i went to : https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/  clicked on Download but it keeps looping back . I finally downloaded plugin-manager.js from https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/  and put it in /lib then I went to Jmeter Options --> plug in manager --> Installed Plugins I see JSON plugins (deprecated)   that was the only one so I installed it.

Comment: After I added JSON plugins (deprecated)   I restarted Jmeter.

Comment: @user3556956 same function you can perform withougt plugin which is Json Extractor perform it with this first and then with plugin.

Comment: @user3556956 you need to put Names of created variables: = accountID JSON Path expression = $..accountID  let me if it works